# Google Maps rendering blank map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to geocode an address, in this case Google HQ, and then find mechanics near that address using the places API.

When I put this same code in my site, the map renders in pieces ( see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152702/map-created-with-google-maps-api-places-api-and-geocode-showing-map-with-ver?noredirect=1#comment41018580_26152702 )

However, in the js fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ze1cpmt5/ ), it doesn't render at all. Same with a page with just the map hosted on my domain.

Actually the code is not the exact same, in the JS Fiddle, It is missing my key because with a key, the API returns an alert saying the API has been blocked. This alert only happens with the key in JSFiddle. Not with the key on my domain.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA',
     dataType: 'json',
     jsonp: 'callback',
     method: 'GET',
     success: function(results){
        console.log(results);
        queryLat = results['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        queryLong = results['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
        function callback(mapsResults, status){
            if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
                    for(var i=0; i<mapsResults.length; i++){
                            var place = mapsResults[i];
                            createMarker(mapsResults[i]);
                    }
            }
        }
        var map;
        var service;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('body'), {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(queryLat, queryLong),
            zoom:15
        });
        var request = {
            location: new google.maps.LatLng(queryLat, queryLong),
            radius:'500',
            query:'mechanic'
        };
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.textSearch(request, callback);
    }
});
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me figure out why it is not rendering on js fiddle and the stand alone page on my domain or why it is rending in pieces in my full-site.

Comment: The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ze1cpmt5/) has a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: createMarker is not defined `

Comment: @geocodezip where do I get the code that defines that function from? I'm following the code at the bottom of this paragraph in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests It doesn't say to import anything.

Comment: Your querySelector does't return a div for the map to be rendered in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncke0q7j/)

Comment: @geocodezip why did it do that? Is there a reason the body did not work?

Comment: @geocodezip can you post that as an answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.querySelector('body') doesn't return a div.

Use a div instead:

```
<div class="map" style="height:400px; width:400px;"></div>
```

Then:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('.map'), {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(queryLat, queryLong),
     zoom: 15
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncke0q7j/)

Comment: because document.querySelector('body') doesn't return a div as my answer says.  You need a HTML Div Element for the map.